# Trigger Insert in table to Update other one

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

I have 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE  IF NOT EXISTS  supply_history(
  id_supply int GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
  id_book int NOT NULL,
  title varchar(150) DEFAULT('None'),
  quantity int NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (id_supply),
  CONSTRAINT fk_id_book
      FOREIGN KEY (id_book)
          REFERENCES books(id_book)
);
```

And:

```
CREATE TABLE  IF NOT EXISTS  quantity_books(
  id_quantity int GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
  id_book int NOT NULL,
  quantity int NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (id_quantity),
  CONSTRAINT fk_id_book
      FOREIGN KEY (id_book)
          REFERENCES books(id_book)
);
```

I would like to sum quantity from quantity_books and supply_history using trigger. Field quantity from quantity_books contains some integer, and after insertion to supply table I would like to update by suming up quantities fields from both tables and save it in quantity_books.

My trigger looks like:

```
-- Trigger to update quantity of books after supply
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS update_quantity_books_after_supply() CASCADE;
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_quantity_books_after_supply()
RETURNS TRIGGER
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $trigger$
    BEGIN
        UPDATE quantity_books AS q
            SET NEW.quantity = supply_history.quantity + OLD.quantity
            FROM supply_history
            WHERE q.id_book = supply_history.id_book;
        RETURN NEW;
    END;
$trigger$;

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trigger_completion_date ON supply_history;
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_insert_supply
   AFTER INSERT
   ON supply_history
   FOR EACH ROW
       EXECUTE FUNCTION update_quantity_books_after_supply();
```

And triggers by insertion:

```
CALL insert_vals_supply(5, null, 200);
```

The problem is with "set" line, tried different combinations with OLD and NEW keywords but didnt work.

Thanks for help

Comment: `SET quantity = q.quantity + NEW.quantity WHERE q.id_book = NEW .id_book` you have access to the updated row, so there's no need to do an `update...from` referencing again the whole table this row goes into. Keep in mind you should add triggers to handle `delete`, `update` and `truncate` on that table - otherwise it'll go out of sync if you watch `insert` only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have access to the updated row via `NEW`, so there's no need to do an `update...from` referencing again the whole table this row goes into. Additionally, you need to handle `delete`, `update` and `truncate` on that table - otherwise it'll go out of sync if you watch `insert` operations only.

Luckily, you can handle `insert`, `update` and `delete` events in a single trigger:

```sql
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS maintain_quantity_books_trigger_function() CASCADE;
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION maintain_quantity_books_trigger_function()
RETURNS TRIGGER
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $trigger$
    BEGIN
        UPDATE quantity_books AS q
            SET quantity = q.quantity 
                           - coalesce(OLD.quantity,0)
                           + coalesce(NEW.quantity,0)
            WHERE q.id_book = coalesce(NEW.id_book,OLD.id_book);
        RETURN null; --it's an after trigger, so this value is ignored
    END;
$trigger$;

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS maintain_quantity_books_trigger ON supply_history;
CREATE TRIGGER maintain_quantity_books_trigger
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF quantity OR DELETE ON supply_history
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION maintain_quantity_books_trigger_function();
```

It's possible even without checking [`TG_OP`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-DML-TRIGGER) thanks to [`coalesce()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) and the behaviour or [visibility of `OLD` and `NEW`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-DML-TRIGGER):

1. `OLD` will be undefined (null) for an `INSERT` trigger, so it won't perform subtraction that's otherwise necessary in case you're doing a `DELETE` or `UPDATE`.
2. In case of `UPDATE` both `OLD` and `NEW` are defined, so you can substract one and add the other, to reflect the correction applied by that update.
3. `DELETE` won't see a `NEW` record, so it will only subtract the quantity it removes, without adding anything.

`TRUNCATE` trigger cannot be declared `FOR EACH ROW` with the rest of events, so it has to be defined separately:

```sql
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS maintain_quantity_books_truncate_trigger_function() CASCADE;
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION maintain_quantity_books_truncate_trigger_function() 
RETURNS TRIGGER LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $trigger$
    BEGIN
      UPDATE quantity_books AS q
      SET quantity = 0;
      RETURN NULL;
    END; 
$trigger$;

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS maintain_quantity_books_truncate_trigger ON supply_history;
CREATE TRIGGER maintain_quantity_books_truncate_trigger 
AFTER TRUNCATE ON supply_history
EXECUTE PROCEDURE maintain_quantity_books_truncate_trigger_function();
```

[Online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/AClHHryk)

Comment: Check out [@Laurenz Albe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6464308/laurenz-albe)'s [post](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/what-to-return-from-a-postgresql-row-level-trigger/) explaining most of this trigger behaviour.

Comment: WORKED FOR ME, thanks for broad clarification. Thank u for help. Last question every trigger should handle all operations on table (insert, delete, update, truncate) otherwise it'll go out of sync everytime?

Comment: You don't need every trigger to handle everything, you just need all operations on the target table to be watched and responded to. If you only watch `insert`, and there happens a `delete` of the recently added row, you'll end up with `quantity_books` showing that quantity even though it was deleted later. If there's an `update` that reduced the quantity by 1, you won't see that reduction. If something wipes your table with a `truncate`, you'll be still seeing those quantities, even though they aren't there anymore.

Comment: Also, make sure that `quantity_books` gets new `books` entered before `supply_history` does. Otherwise you could add a book to `supply_history` and it'll go unnoticed because the `update` statement just won't find anything to update in `quantity_books`. You could use a trigger on `books`, that for each new book adds its blank record with zero quantity to `quantity_books`. Or change the `update` statement to an upsert [`insert...on conflict do update`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT) or a [`merge`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-merge.html).